# LightGBM on RPi 4B Ubuntu fails to load model

Tags: ubuntu, julia, raspberry-pi4, lightgbm

I am using Julia 1.5 on a raspberry pi 4b 8GB running Ubuntu 20.04 64 bit. I had created a lightGBM model on my Windows laptop and saved the model to a file. This loads fine on my windows laptop and executes properly. But when I am trying to load it in Raspberry PI, I get below error.
I checked and found that the /home/pi/.julia/packages/LightGBM/My6MK/src/lib_lightgbm.so  file exists.
I have tried to remove the LightGBM Package and add it back again. But issue still persists.
Please let me know if you need more details.

```
loadmodel(estimator, "/home/pi/softwares/julia/lightgbmModel.jld2")
ERROR: could not load library "/home/pi/.julia/packages/LightGBM/My6MK/src/lib_lightgbm.so"
/home/pi/.julia/packages/LightGBM/My6MK/src/lib_lightgbm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Stacktrace:
 [1] LGBM_BoosterCreateFromModelfile(::String) at /home/pi/.julia/packages/LightGBM/My6MK/src/wrapper.jl:101
 [2] loadmodel(::LGBMClassification, ::String) at /home/pi/.julia/packages/LightGBM/My6MK/src/utils.jl:72
 [3] top-level scope at REPL[16]:1
```

Comment: Hey, make sure the path you are using is absolute.

Comment: I would also validate that the file path is correct outside of Julia using the terminal

Comment: Yes the path is correct and absolute. I had used Julia 1.4.2 to build the model on my laptop. So I downloaded that version as well on the raspberry pi, but I am getting same error even in that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem building .Net project on MacOs and then running on Raspberry PI 4. It looks like the library 'lib_lightgbm.so' distributed with NuGet package manager works with other Linux distributions but it is not the right library for Raspberry.

I compiled 'lib_lightgbm.so' on Raspberry using

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM ; cd LightGBM
mkdir build ; cd build
cmake ..
make -j4
```

and then manually copied the compiled library **'lib_lightgbm.so'** into your project directory (replace the existing one). That worked for me.

Comment: Thank you very much. This definitely worked. Though I had to take some additional steps. For other users who face this, please see below if this helps in addition to above.

Comment: First of all I had to use sudo for all the above commands on rpi. After doing all above steps, julia gave an error for libstdc++.so.6 version mismatch. For this I did "sudo apt-get upgrade; sudo apt-get install libstdc++6;" then I copied the update libstdc++.so.6 file from RPI OS folder to julia folder inside julia's lib "cp /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 /home/pi/julia/lib/julia/"